# iPhone navigation bar rotation issue when coming back from background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, background, orientation

Ok, so after weeks of headache, I've given up and decided to turn to expert resource online!

Basically, I am trying to get my iphone application to view in a forced landscape mode (to be precise, for a graph) for just 1 view controller in otherwise a portrait-orientation dominated navigation-bar application.

I got everything working the way it should, EXCEPT when I put the application into background and return, the application returns with the navigation bar moved to where it usually sits in Portrait orientation mode but rotated 90', whilst every others like status bar, the main view are all still in landscape mode.

I've tried to manually correct the navigation bar orientation afterwards, but cocoa seems to ignore this bit of code. It's almost as if the self.view.transform doesn't work when the application returns from background mode. Any suggestions?

LandscapeViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (90) / 180.0));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
}
```

**This image shows you can see what I mean**

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1Si.png

Comment: I don't know wether it'll help, but you should understand that navigation controllers view doesn't belong to your view controllers view. It is a view of UINavigationController instance. So when you call self.view.transform... and self.view.bounds... it won't effect navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but still isn't fixed. Looks like the picture here - http://i.imgur.com/Qx1Si.png

Answer (score 0):

You should not always return NO from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: but return YES for the orientation you support. The iOS then handles the rest.

Comment: I've done that. Also put a breakpoint on shouldAutorotate... to confirm that is being called upon returning from background. However, it still doesn't solve my problem.